# Can't access values in an array that's part of a foreach loop in powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm relatively new to powershell and coding and am having issues accessing the values in an array. I'm trying to loop thru a set of files using foreach and count the number of messages in each file. And then have the count for each file put in to an array so I can assign it to a variable. When I do write-host $data[0] it returns all the values. If I do write-host $data[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1mZO.jpg) it returns nothing. It seems like these values are all being stored as one instead of as individual numbers. How do I get each value and then assign it to a variable. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$FilePath = 'some file path here'
$TodaysDate = (Get-Date -format "MM-dd-yyyy")

ForEach($file in Get-ChildItem $FilePath -exclude *.ps1,*.xml,*.xls | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -ge $TodaysDate})
{
    $data = ,@(Get-Content $file | Where-Object {$_.Contains("MSH|")}).Count
    write-host $data[0]
 }
exit
```

[powershell result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1mZO.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
$data = ,@(Get-Content $file | Where-Object {$_.Contains("MSH|")}).Count
```

you are creating an array of a single element (the count). What you want to do is add to $data each time:

```
$data += ,@(Get-Content $file | Where-Object {$_.Contains("MSH|")}).Count
```

But given your description, I think you may want a hashtable, using the filename as a key:

```
$data = @{} #init hashtable
ForEach($file in Get-ChildItem $FilePath -exclude *.ps1,*.xml,*.xls | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -ge $TodaysDate})
{
    $data[$file] = @(Get-Content $file | Where-Object {$_.Contains("MSH|")}).Count
}

write-output $data
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I don't know much about hashtables, but read a little bit. Seems like this will work. But, now how do I pull just the counts for each file from the table. The file name's include today's date, therefore will be changing every day, so I can't grab the value by the key like $data."filename". I tried this, not sure if this is the right way to go about it: 
    $Count = $data.GetEnumerator() | ? {$_.key -like "file_name*"}
    
    write-output $Count     This is giving me the file name and the count. I just want to assign the count to the variable.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I just needed to add .value to my variable: `$Count = $data.GetEnumerator() | ? {$_.key -like "filename*"}            write-output $Count.value`